# How to recognise numbers in images using Netlogo programming sudoku

Tags: grid, numbers, cells, sudoku, netlogo

Hi everyone i have a problem of being able to identify numbers in an image using netlogo programming, Please any ideas or techniques on how to be able to identify numbers in a cell? I am making a sudoku game using netlogo coding. First i need to import an image into the screen and be able to setup the image.

I need to be able to use the image(s) to generate random sudoku puzzles without any repetitions. But first to make the sudoku game i have to be able to use the numbers from the image.

I have got this code so far

```
to setup
    clear-all
    import-pcolors "s1.png"
    reset-ticks
end

to go
    ask patches with [pcolor != black]
    [ set pcolor white ]
end
```

Please i need a simple algorithm for recognizing numbers in sudoku netlogo

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you are asking is how to do OCR ([optical character recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)) in NetLogo.

This is not something that NetLogo does "out of the box", and as far as I know, there is currently no [NetLogo extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions) that does that either.

And no, there is no "simple algorithm for recognising numbers" that you can just copy-paste in your NetLogo code.

So what can you do?

In theory, you could [write a new NetLogo extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API) that interfaces with an existing OCR package, but that's not a trivial task.

You could also ask the [NetLogo users group](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/netlogo-users/) if anyone has ever tried to do that before. Maybe someone there will have more insight for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I would do 10 breads of turtles with shapes "0".."9". So I would not have to recognize numbers but simply recognize breed of turtles.

Comment: 10 breeds of turtles with shapes 0..9. But how would it work with the sudoku image. and how would i be able to form a generated sudoku using this method

Answer (score 0):

You could try and build the pattern recognition within NetLogo, provided your individual Sudoku cells  have a decent resolution (say at least 9x9 patches).  Then match each cell to a predefined 9x9 patch pattern representing each of the 9 digits.  Save your result as the 9 different breeds of turtles.

(I have not tried this myself)